# Alternative to PHP $mysql->fetch_assoc()?

Tags: php, mysql

So basically I have the following loop to iterate database rows:

```
while($row = $mysql->fetch_assoc())
```

But I need to access the rows **before** this loop as well. So, I do this:

```
$inside = $mysql->fetch_assoc()
```

and **$mysql** *loses* its rows. When it gets to the while loop it simply does not enter it as the condition becomes NULL.

I tried the following

```
while($row = $inside)
```

but this just waits until timeout (loops indefinitely).

Any idea on how I could perform this, making up for the requirements above? Thank you very much for your help...

Comment: You could set the row to an array in the while, then access that array later when you need the rows for the second time..

Answer (score 4):

After you do this :

```
while ( $row = $mysql->fetch_assoc() )
```

The internal pointer of `$resul` is at the end. So you can move it to the beginning again :

```
$mysql->data_seek( 0 ); 
while ( $row = $mysql->fetch_assoc() )
```

All the rows are available again.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$mysql->data_seek(0)` before to reset the row counter on your second loop iteration. It will allow you to loop through the rows again. See [this helpful post](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php#85629) for an example.